# How to populate email on unsubscribe page

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, unsubscribe, dynamics-marketing

We have hosted Subscription Center Dynamic 365 marketing form on external website unsubscribe page. Once user click on unsubscribe link in email, they redirected to this unsubscribe page. On this page we need to show user's email address. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Add the "E-mail" marketing form field to the marketing form.

As this is a subscription center, it should automatically prefill with the contact's email, when they access the form using the link from the email

Comment: I think it's done but still email is not showing. Instead it just shows placeholder {{contact.emailaddress1}} on page. Is there any configuration changes neededfor this?

Comment: There shouldn't be any configuration needed. The email will only be prefilled on the form when it is accessed via a link in an email. Is that how you are checking it, or are you accessing the form directly?

Comment: We access the form from an link in email called unsubscribe. Since it was not working so now we have added query string in unsubscribe and capture the email from URL and show on unsubscribe page